# git conflict keep original upstream

Tags: git, github

I made a copy of a repo from github. Was just playing around the code a bit, made a branch committed that changes locally and now the original code is updated,so I want to delete whatever I did to my fork and get changes made by the upstream.

I get a conflict if I do

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
#Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

and gives in two file names showing few changes which I never did.

So I did a git status which gives me a new filename(which I never made but was made by my upstream) and Unmerged paths:

```
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
```

for two files.

I want all the new changes and destroy mine. What could possibly be the solution and why does GIT wants me to add a file I never made?

Comment: so you want me to do something like git fetch orgin and then git reset --hard origin/master? where would I get changes from upstream in this scenario?

Comment: I still get the same conflict message after I do what is suggested in the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abort the conflicted merge:

```
git merge --abort
```

then set your local repo to the same commit as upstream, discarding local changes:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

As for your question:

> why does GIT wants me to add a file I never made?

It doesn't. It's telling you to resolve the conflicts in the files you changed, then `git add <file>` on those files, to mark the edited versions as resolved and OK to commit.